# Magento2: How can I add Magento_GiftMessage to checkout (billing step > afterMethods)?

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, uicomponent

I want to add the "Gift Options" (Magento_GiftMessage) to the checkout billing step.
Currently it's displayed only on cart page:
[image]

& I want it (also) on checkout, under the payment methods list.

---

At first I tried to add this code to `checkout_index_index.xml`:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\GiftMessage\Block\Cart\GiftOptions" name="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options" template="cart/gift_options.phtml" cacheable="false" after="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="giftOptionsCart" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message</item>
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message</item>
                            <item name="formTemplate" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message-form</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

& It actually worked, but it's not where I want it (it's now under the whole "checkout.root" block, at the bottom, pretty far from the payment methods list...)
So I played with it a little more & figured out that I need to somehow add this block to the "afterMethods" item inside the "checkout.root" block, but so far I couldn't figure out how to make it work or how can I add a block to this type of structure (if it's even possible).

---

-- Any idea?

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: @jackcar, Not yet...

Comment: @Pini if you get this done plz share.